# Read NFC messages on credit cards

Tags: android, nfc

I want to be able to read the NFC messages of different cards.
Everything works well when I use the card of my company that are NDEF-MifareClassic-NfcA.
When I try with my credit card or the Underground-Oyster card, nothing is detected even if I can see that other apps can detect these cards.

This is what I have in the Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nfc">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NFC">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.actions"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NFC.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="developer.android.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/index.html" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is what I have in the `@xml/nfc_tech_filter` file referenced in the Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some Java code in your question, that shows what you are doing when your App is started by the NFC intent you requested in the Manifest and most likely missing some Java Code to request and handle NFC data when your App is already running.

Comment: It was working for other cards so I assumed it wasn't a problem with the activity that just needs to handle the `intent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I had put the section:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.actions"
    android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
```

in the wrong place. It should have been along with the filter in the `<activity>`.